# how to avoid 'ORA-21561: OID generation failed' while using NodeJS oracledb on ubuntu 14

Tags: node.js, oracle

I'm setting up a Ubuntu instance to become a remote NodeJS oracle client.

The Node version is 4.4.7

I've installed

oracle-instantclient12.1-basic-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm,

oracle-instantclient12.1-devel-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm,

and oracle-instantclient12.1-sqlplus-12.1.0.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm packages

I've installed oracledb node package:  sudo npm install -g oracledb

I've installed libaio:  sudo apt-get install libaio1
I've configured my dbconfig.js as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  user          : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_USER || "myID",

  password      : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_PASSWORD || "myPASS",

  connectString : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_CONNECTIONSTRING || "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=my_remote_host)(Port=1560))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=srptprd)(SERVICE_NAME = my_service_name)))",

  externalAuth  : process.env.NODE_ORACLEDB_EXTERNALAUTH ? true : false
};
```

I've configured my connect.js as follows:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var dbConfig = require('./dbconfig.js');

oracledb.getConnection(
  {
    user          : dbConfig.user,
    password      : dbConfig.password,
    connectString : dbConfig.connectString
  },
  function(err, connection)
  {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      return;
    }
    console.log('Connection was successful!');

    connection.release(
      function(err)
      {
        if (err) {
          console.error(err.message);
          return;
        }
      });
  });
```

When I run "node connect.js" I get this error:

```
ORA-21561: OID generation failed
```

What can I do to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, all I had to do was to add the actual host name of my server to the /etc/hosts file:  127.0.0.1 localhost **my_host_name**

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed with a simple edit to your hosts file.

- Find the name of your local-machine by running hostname in your local-terminal

  `$hostname`
- Edit your local hosts file

  `$vi /etc/hosts`

  assuming $hostname gives local_machine_name append it to your localhost ,

  `127.0.0.1 localhost local_machine_name`

press esc and type wq! to save

Cheers!

Comment: In my case, to show the hostname, I need to type 'hostname' command in the terminal.